# Trying to blend diffuse texture with cubemap makes object invisible

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm following the learnopengl website and I'm trying to combine the diffuse texture I have on the object with the calculated reflection/refraction vectors but it makes the object invisible. When I set `gl_FragColor = environmentColor;` it works fine but the moment I try to multipliy, add, or mix the diffuse texture the object becomes invisible. Here is the code I have:

```
vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);

vec3 viewVector = normalize(worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition);
vec3 reflectedVector = reflect(viewVector, norm);
vec3 refractedVector = refract(viewVector, norm, 0.68047f);
vec4 reflectedColor = texture(skybox, reflectedVector);
vec4 refractedColor = texture(skybox, refractedVector);
vec4 environmentColor = mix(reflectedColor, refractedColor, 0.5f);

gl_FragColor = mix(texture(texture_diffuse1, TexCoords), environmentColor, 0.5f);
```

Comment: Does the texture work? That is, do you see the (unmixed) texture with `gl_FragColor = texture(texture_diffuse1, TexCoords);`?

Comment: Yes the texture works fine as well. It's just the moment I try to combine the two in any way the object then becomes invisible.

Comment: Okay. Any shader program compilation errors? Any errors when updating the uniforms?

Comment: Nope, no compilation errors at all, I even tried mixing the xyz values statically as such: `gl_FragColor = vec4(objectColor.x, objectColor.y, environmentColor.z, 1.0f);` but the moment I do anything like this then it just becomes invisible again.

Comment: What are the types of `texture_diffuse1` and `TexCoords`?

Comment: texture_diffuse1 is a sampler2D and TexCoords is vec2

Comment: That seems correct. I'm not seeing the problem. Perhaps try editing your program down to a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake for anyone else that might have this same issue: I was setting the location of the cubemap textures to be the same as my sampler2D textures. I simply modified the `glActiveTexture` for the cubemap textures to be using GL_TEXTURE1 instead of GL_TEXTURE0 and initialized the uniforms to point to 1 and everything works now.